# Retrieve the custom user profile properties using JSOM with rest api and display it into a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-2013, jquery-ajaxq, sharepoint-jsom

How to retrieve the custom user profile properties using JSOM with rest api.

As i need to retrieve Employee Cost Center(Custom property) of current login user
but the below code is not working.

```
<script>
```

$.ajax({

```
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",  
        headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
        success: function (data) {  
            try {  

               // userDisplayName=data.d.DisplayName;   
               //AccountName = data.d.AccountName;  
                var properties = data.d.UserProfileProperties.results;  
                for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {  



                    if (properties[i].Key == "Employee Cost Center") {  
                       var CostCenter= properties[i].Value;  
                    }  

                                       }  

                $('#Diviision').text(CostCenter);  

            } catch (err2) {  

            }  
        },  
        error: function (jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {  
            alert(errorThrown);  
        }  
    });  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the code as below:

```
<div id="Diviision"></div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
    //execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {          
            var properties = data.d.UserProfileProperties.results;  
            for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                if (properties[i].Key == "Employee Cost Center") {  
                    var CostCenter= properties[i].Value;
                    $('#Diviision').text(CostCenter);
                }
            }           
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("Failed to get details");                
        }
    });
});
</script>
```